# ffmpeg: freeze frame into video, one pass

Tags: video, ffmpeg

My goal is to grab the first frame of a video, fade in from black on this freeze frame, and then continue with the rest of the video.

I can grab the first frame easily enough:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0.0 -i master.mov -frames:v 1 firstframe.png
```

Given this image, I can then fade it in over 1 second, and then concat with the original video:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i firstframe.png -i master.mov -filter_complex \
"[0:v] trim=duration=1, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1 [fadein]; \
[fadein][1:v]concat=n=2, format=yuv420p [output]" \
-map [output] output.mov
```

My question, is it possible to do this in a single pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i master.mov -filter_complex \
"[0]trim=start_frame=0:end_frame=1,loop=F:1:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,fade=st=0:d=1[fade]; \
 [fade][0]concat,format=yuv420p" output.mov
```

Replace **F** with the frame rate of your video.

Comment: This works! It also works with `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS`, which shows how I don't quite understand how `setpts` works in ffmpeg ..

Comment: Some files, usually TS files, such as those recorded on a DVR, can have non-zero STARTPTS, so `PTS-STARTPTS` assigns a new series where STARTPTS is zero. My expression amounts to the same thing for a constant frame rate video. .